# Make transparent background apart from web ticker

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a BBC news ticker on my web page, [Link](http://www.dataman-solution.co.uk/bbc.php)

Basically this is a news feed in a div box on a blank page, What I want to do is make the white background tranparent so that a page under this one can be seen, esentially this BBC web ticker would be an overlay

Can anyone offer and suggestions please?

The code is here [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwl707/AmkHb/) if it helps (It will not work as it requires another file, but I hope it shows the styling etc..

```
    body { 
width: 1800px;
margin: auto;
background-color:transparent ???? 
    }
```

thanks

** I cannot access the image that this would overlay **

Comment: Hey.. It is unclear what do you need exactly...

Comment: Do you have an example of what happens when you insert it on another page?

How do you try insert the ticker on the other page?

Could it be an issue with eg. with the background-color of that container?

Comment: I need to explain myself a bit more, If possible I would like to open two browsers on my desktop, one ontop of the other, the first would have an image and the second would have my webticker , so that the image shows through but the ticker overlays it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-color:transparent` means element will display the background-color as of it's parent.

So you need to set some color to body element

```
  body {
   background-color:Yellow;
  }
```

Now any element over this which having transparent background will show Yellow as Background color for it.

If you doesn't want background-color for your `Feed` div then just remove this line

```
#bbctext {
   //background-color: #61A2A7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
background-color:transparent;
```

Does indeed make the background of the selected element transparent (in this case "body").

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background to be transparent then you can use RGBA;

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

WARNING it only works in more modern browsers. Will not work in IE6, 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transparent version of the image you want as the background and use that as the background of the body instead.